# Эффективность условия в join

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня вопрос касательно условия в запросах `join`.

В чем разница касательно производительности между следующими запросами:

```
Select c.FIO from Clients c
    Inner Join ClientsDuplicates cd On cd.client_id = c.client_id and cd.amount = 1


Select c.FIO from Clients c
    Inner Join ClientsDuplicates cd On cd.client_id = c.client_Id
    Where cd.amount = 1
```

Comment: я лучше вручу удочку, чем буду давать рыбу... В Sql Server Management Studio (если мы про MS SQL) в окне с запросом есть кнопка "Include Actual Execution Plan", которая после вызова запроса покажет план выполнения (собственно по нему и сравнивать) и временнЫе задержки на каждом из этапов. Времени единичного запуска, конечно,  верить смысла мало, но план выполнения заслуживает полного доверия в пределах той же версии СУБД.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для `join` (`inner`) никакой разницы. Query processor построит идентичные планы в обоих случаях. Также, используя, например, свойство коммутативности внутреннего соединения (`A join B` = `B join A`) можно записать ещё одну форму:

```
select c.FIO
from ClientsDuplicates cd
    inner join Clients c on c.client_id = cd.client_id
where cd.amount = 1
```

или вот другая форма:

```
;with cd1 as (select client_id from ClientsDuplicates where amount = 1)
select c.FIO
from Clients c
    inner join cd1 on cd1.client_id = cd1.client_id
```

ещё одна вариация:

```
;with cd1 as (select client_id from ClientsDuplicates where amount = 1)
select c.FIO
from cd1
    inner join Clients c on c.client_id = cd1.client_id
```

Все эти формы данного запроса вернут одинаковый результат, и будут иметь идентичный план исполнения, поскольку, с точки зрения реляционной алгебры, эти отношения эквиваленты, или, точнее сказать, они *приводимы* друг к другу.

Query processor не выполняет написанное прямо так как это написано (исключая случаи с различными `hint`), перед выполнением проводится оптимизация запроса. Приведу аналогию. Допустим у нас есть математическое выражение `5*3 + 4*3`. Можно вычислить его прямо так как написано, и на это потребуется три действия, а можно заметить, что это то же самое, что `(5+4)*3`, и это уже два действия. И хотя это весьма отдалённая аналогия, но задача оптимизатора видеть подобное, видеть выгоду там, где её можно извлечь. и, что касается данного конкретного случая, то Sql Server это умеет достаточно давно.

Последняя форма запроса (`with cd1 as () select ... from cd1 join c`) наиболее наглядно отражает реальный план исполнения данного запроса. Сначала разрешаются известности, потом неизвестности. Если какой то предикат позволяет уменьшить число строк, которые будут участвовать в соединении на следующем этапе, и его можно применить *перед* непосредственно соединением, не искажая результат, то он будет применён.

Разница в положении условия в `on` либо `where` будет тогда, когда это будет не `inner join`, а `outer` (например, `left join`). Разница в первую очередь семантическая, и, как следствие, в производительности. Это можно видеть на следующем примере.

Пусть есть данные вида:

```
declare @group table (id int, code varchar(10), name varchar(10))
declare @data table (groupid int, data varchar(10))
insert into @group values
    (1, 'G1', 'Group 1'), (2, 'G2', 'Group 2')
insert into @data values
    (1, 'D1.1'), (1, 'D1.2'),
    (2, 'D2.1'), (2, 'D2.2'),
    (NULL, 'D_.1'), (NULL, 'D_.2')
```

Сравните результат следующих двух запросов:

```
select d.data, g.name
from @data d
    left join @group g on g.id = d.groupid
where g.code = 'G1'
```

и

```
select d.data, g.name
from @data d
    left join @group g on g.id = d.groupid and g.code = 'G1'
```

Самантика следующая:

**Первый запрос**: 1) хочу элементы данных и имя группы, если оно есть; 2) из всего этого хочу только те пары, у которых код группы `G1`. Фактически исполнится как `inner join`. **Второй запрос**: хочу все элементы данных и имя группы, но имя группы я хочу только, если это группа с кодом `G1`.

Так как второй запрос берёт все элементы данных, а первый не все, то, естественно, производительность будет отличаться. В зависимости от количества данных в обеих таблицах и индексов это могут быть и тысячи раз. Однако, при разной семантике сравнивать производительность, полагаю не совсем корректно.

Comment: Не могли бы вы подкрепить цифрами и ссылками ответ? Вопрос действительно интересный и хороший ответ будет долго приносить славу его автору.

Comment: Поддерживаю @LEQADA в плане может Вы распишите чуть более подробно. я так понимаю что в первом варианте сначала выберуться все необходимые записи по условию `where` потом только будет соединение, во втором же случае будут выбраны все записи, соединены, и только потом накладываться ограничение